# Nginx basic auth password not working

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set up basic auth on a subfolder with nginx.

```
location ^~ /Docs/ {
   auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
   auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/Docs/.htpasswd; //also tried the path in quotes
}
```

I have tried numerous methods to generate a password (e.g apache's `htpasswd`) but I am not able to log in at /Docs with the username and password specified in .htpasswd. I see the authentication dialog with 'Restricted Area' but the password is not accepted.

I've tried the methods [here](http://kbeezie.com/protecting-folders-with-nginx/):

Comment: Have you looked in Nginx error logs for any messages?

Comment: @Mxx D'oh forgot to do that. I can see lots of '5308#0: *17714 no user/password was provided for basic authentication'

Comment: Try this as your .htpasswd file `qqq:$apr1$n8K8x5Ff$8SmG1.VuQ6/Zm/LF2NFkX1` both username and password are "qqq"

Comment: @Mxx tried that got the same error 'no user/password was provided for basic authentication'

Comment: However, I think that error may be normal for the initial request to the url which doesn't include the user/pass i.e before the auth dialog pops up.

Comment: Is it the only location set up with basic authentication in your configuration?

Comment: @GuidoVaccarella yes, I think so. I didn't configure it but there are no other mentions of auth_basic in the main 'default' file in /sites-available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by a Squid caching proxy which was not passing authentication headers correctly. This was proved by running something similar to the following:

```
curl -i --user qqq:qqq http://target.server/Docs/dump.php |grep AUTH
```

where dump.php contains `<php phpinfo();`

In the case of the server behind squid, the output of that command was empty and I would expect to see mention of `_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an absolute location path?

`location /Docs {
  auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
  auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/Docs/.htpasswd;
}`

If that gets you further along, you may want to either (A) move the password file outside of the web root directory, or (B) protect the password file from being served:

`location ~ /\. { deny  all; }`

And are you sure the file you have created is readable by the user nginx is running as?

Comment: yep, have tried this. Nginx runs as www-data on Ubuntu AFAIK. I have tried chown'ing everything to www-data:www-data. That dot file rule already exists in server {}